# Can we retrieve only one record in DynamoDB

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I'm curious to know that "**can we retrieve only one record in DynamoDB**"? I know that I can retrieve only one record by coding layer like `let singleRow = data.Items[0]` but it's not good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. `GetItem`. If your using the node.js AWS Dynamodb Sdk the `GetItem` function retrievies only one item.

**Example**

```
 var params = {
  Key: {
   "Artist": {
     S: "Acme Band"
    }, 
   "SongTitle": {
     S: "Happy Day"
    }
  }, 
  TableName: "Music"
 };
 dynamodb.getItem(params, function(err, data) {
   if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
   else     console.log(data);           // successful response
   /*
   data = {
    Item: {
     "AlbumTitle": {
       S: "Songs About Life"
      }, 
     "Artist": {
       S: "Acme Band"
      }, 
     "SongTitle": {
       S: "Happy Day"
      }
    }
   }
   */
 });
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#getItem-property